# magento2 add shipping address telephone validation start with 9

Tags: magento2, form-validation

I want a validation on telephone field when adding shipping address.

Number will start only with 7 Or 8 Or 9.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this following script

```
function validatePhone() {
var a = document.getElementById(txtPhone).value;
    var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
   if (a.charAt(0) =="9" || a.charAt(0) =="8" || a.charAt(0) =="7" ){
  alert("");
   }
   else{
   if (filter.test(a)) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I  have problem about the file location where i have to put the code...

Comment: Did you have "id" or "class" for the telephone input field ??